# How to add variable variations for products in Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, logic

I am designing a database where the user can add variations of the product.
For example a shirt can have variations like color. But a battery may have variation about Voltage, Power etc.
***Different products can have different variations based on their different features, attributes***.
How can I deal with this issue. Because
**I don't want to specify the possible variations beforehand.**

Comment: This is something of a FAQ, but the solution depends upon your specific needs and preferences.

Comment: If you're designing a MySql database structure, you really should be aware of the relational model and if you are, it's really obvious what you need to do.  Do a Google of "relational model" and you should be able to find what you want.  If you don't, do come back here with what you found and I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: I just want a hint how to deal with "variable no of attributes" problem. Should I use external file (e.g json) and get further details from this?

Comment: *I am designing a database where the user can add variations of the product. For example a shirt can have variations like color.* A variation as a property of the entity, or variations values list? Maybe EAV model is safe for your task?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ProductGroup like **food-tech-health** some etc,

you can create a table like **Groupsvariations**

variations can define one Time and it **relationship more than one** product groups

guıd,topId(int),ProductGroupId(int),Variatoins(nvarchar)

example
[tableDesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CHuU.png)

example [rowValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FZp3.png)

Comment: But also here is a need for variable no of variations.